# How to compare corresponding positions between two lists of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started with Python. Maybe this is a little too much, but I'm trying to do a simple sudoku, not a sudoku solver, but a program where you put the solution (the sudoku complete), the puzzle (the sudoku incomplete) and then the user inputs are loaded on the puzzle.
Once the all elements of the puzzle are the same that on the complete, the program finishes.

I did it on C. Very poorly, but it works.

My problem here is that I can't seem to understand how to compare two lists of lists.
I have this (I'm using 4x4 until all the tests are ok):

```
sudoComplete = [
               [1,2,3,4],
               [3,4,2,1],
               [4,3,1,2],
               [2,1,4,3]
               ]
sudoIncomp = [
             [0,2,3,0],
             [3,0,0,1],
             [4,0,0,2],
             [0,1,4,0]
             ]
```

What I want to do is what I did on my C code (or something similar):

```
int compareSudo(int sudoResuelto[4][4], int sudoTerminado[4][4])
{
    int state;
    int i=0, j=0;
    for (; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        for (; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (sudoComplete [i][j] == sudoIncomp[i][j])
                {
                    state= 1;
                } else
                {
                    state= 0;
                    break;
                }
        }
        j=0;
        if (state == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Sorry it doesn't have comments.

The return needs to be one thing. It doesn't matter if it's a number or a boolean.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So you want to compare that the "sudoku complete" and the "sudoku incomplete" are the same?

Comment: sudoComplete == sudoComplete

Comment: You can directly compare two (nested) lists for equality, including elements. Is that what you want?

Comment: I think your C code fails to skip the positions where `sudoIncomp` is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand task, than you just need to check equality of lists:

```
result = list1 == list2
```

**Obvious explanation:** If lists are equal `result` will contain `True`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to check that the matrices are equal in all positions where the second one is non-zero. This function should do it (however, it assumes and does not check that the two inputs have the same dimensions):

```
    def compareSudo(full, partial):
        for i in range(0,len(partial)):
            for j in range(0, len(partial[i])):
                if partial[i][j] != 0 and partial[i][j] != full[i][j]:
                    return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudoComplete == sudoComplete
```

Returns true if the two lists are equal.
If you are interested in knowing the indices of the correct values

```
np.where(np.array(sudoComplete) == np.array(sudoIncomp))
```

In detail: 
with this line of code you find the matrix with `'True'` in the positions where the lists have the same elements:

```
np.array(sudoComplete) == np.array(sudoIncomp)
```

`np.where()` returns the indices of true values